# How do I fix "Alert! Failed to detect one or more drives during post?"

Tags: boot

After installing Linux Mint 17 xfce on my Optiplex 755 Computer, I received the following message on boot:

```
Intel(R) Matrix Storage Manager
Option ROM v7.6.1.1001 ICH9R
Copyright(C) 2003-07 Intel Corporation. All rights Reserved.

Drive 2 not found: Serial ATA, SATA-2 Floppy diskette see failure Alert!
Failed to detect one or more drives during post. Strike the F1 key to continue,
F2 to run the setup utility. Press F5 to run onboard diagonostics_
```

I am not sure what the problem is and how to fix it in order to stop the message from occurring. I am still in the process of trying to get grub working. How do I fix "Alert! Failed to detect one or more drives during post?"

Comment: Disable the Floppy in your BIOS by pressing F2.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your first boot device have been set on `Floppy diskette` ! so change first boot device to `Hard drive` in **bios setting** !